# can we automate html5 webpage using selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My application contains html5 webpage.I am trying to inspects and trying to get ids/classname locators. But I am not able get locators of the required web elements in HTML 5.

I saw most of them contains .js are assigned to SRC attribute.

Can any one suggest me how can I automate HTML 5 webpage.

Comment: I know that you can automate an html5 page with selenium webdriver, javascript includes are in the form of `<script src='file.js'></script>` are you trying to target a script tag for some reason?

Comment: Yes, but everything is SRC="www.js attributes.where can I see the id's or xpaths of particular button

Comment: In Chrome or Firefox, right-click and click **Inspect Element** and view the loaded HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Try using XPaths where you cannot find the element by ID or CSS. Yes you can find elements with Selenium on html 5.

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp